# Drinfeld module whose exponential function has infinitely many zero coefficients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I wonder if there exists a Drinfeld module $\rho$ over $\mathbb F_q[T]$ such that its exponential function $\exp_\rho=\sum_{n\ge0}c_nz^{q^n}$ is such that infinitely many $c_n$'s are zero.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean with an exponential of a Drinfeld module?